# Truck Routing in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, software-recommendations, maps

I know that Google Maps does not have a truck routing feature , ie, changing the route if a low bridge is detected.

Is there a way I can implement this in Google Maps using a 3rd party API?

If yes, then which APIs are supported and preferable.

Comment: Which area of the world are you interested in, for truck routing?

Comment: US and Canada Region

Comment: Check smarttruckroute.com I saw under FAQ API for developers

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [OpenRouteService.org](http://bit.ly/1S5pZOL). This OSM-based routing engine has a heavy vehicle profile, where you can specify dimension limitations (e.g., length, width, height, weight) or load characteristics (e.g., hazardous materials) of a heavy vehicle. The API is described on the [wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService#OpenRouteService_API).

Comment: Is it possible to use the ORS truck routing api in google maps?

Comment: At the moment ORS does not support routing in North America. For more details see [ORS coverage](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/File:ORS_Coverage.png).

I am not entirely sure if Google allows to visualize OpenStreetMap data on top of their maps. If it is not forbidden, you can visualize an ORS route on top of Google Maps using its [api to draw polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple).